# how to remove a part of line in text file using linux command

Tags: linux

From the line

```
/mnt/sampleserver/test_1/myfile.pdf
```

in my text file I want to remove

```
/mnt/sampleserver/test_1/
```

Please suggest me how to do it using linux commands.

Comment: Use [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways:

```
file="/mnt/sampleserver/test_1/myfile.pdf"

$ echo ${file##*/}
myfile.pdf

$ echo $file | cut -d/ -f5
myfile.pdf

$ echo $file | awk -F/ '{print $5}'
myfile.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'basename' command. Something like this: `basename /mnt/sampleserver/test_1/myfile.pdf`

Comment: `basename` will give `myfile.pdf`

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, the OP says “remove”, not “extract”.

Comment: Yes - he wanted to remove /mnt/sampleserver/test_1/

Comment: Oooops my fault, sorry I understood it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any text processing tool, for example, sed:

```
% echo "/mnt/sampleserver/test_1/myfile.pdf" | sed -e 's|/mnt/sampleserver/test_1/||'
myfile.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should get you going. (Note the "\" for escape character)

/bin/sed -i "s//mnt/sampleserver/test_1///"

Comment: /bin/sed -i "s/\/mnt\/sampleserver\/test_1\////"  file_name